# Tap event testing with protractor and appium

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, appium

I have html with `on-tap= doThis()`. When going to test it with protractor and appium the `.click` event does not fire it off. It seems like a really simple thing to do, but yet I can not find any documentation on touch events for iOS appium. Does this have to do with the driver I am using?

```js
// javascript
// assuming we have an initialized `driver` object for an app

driver.contexts().then(function (contexts) { 

  return driver.context(contexts[1]); // choose the webview context
})

// do some web testing
.elementsByCss('.green_button').click()

.context('NATIVE_APP') // leave webview context

// do more native stuff here if we want

.quit() // stop webdrivage
```

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, having consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Comment: I have edited your question to tidy up the embedded code a bit. On this site, users are encouraged to edit and re-edit their questions to improve them as much as possible; if there is anything extra you think would be useful, or any clarification you can add, feel free to [edit] the question further.